# No compile error

Tags: excel, vba

When I execute Test1, I get the message `Run time error 13, Type mismatch` when the code encounters Test2 - which I would expect. What does surprise me is the fact I'm not getting an `argument type mismatch` error message when I compile.  I must be missing something, can someone set me straight?

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim w As Worksheet
  Set w = ActiveSheet
  Test2 w
End Sub

Sub Test2(r As Range)
'do something
End Sub
```

Comment: It throws compile error in 3 cases: 1) The assignment is not valid. 2) You pass an object to a procedure that expects a single property or value. 3) You use a module or project name where an expression was expected. 
Took info from [Type mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/type-mismatch)

Comment: @AntiDrondert, I just amazed that I've never encountered this situation before now!